# Prevent form validation unless at least two fields are filled

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

I am developing an app in Django.

I am overwriting my model clean method in order to prevent form validation unless at least one field form a certain set of fields is filled.

```
def clean(self):
    if not (self.field1 or self.field2  or self.field3):
        raise ValidationError("you have to compile at least one field")
```

Now, how can I tell my code to prevent form validation unless at least two fields of the same set of fields are filled?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `clean` method to count the number of filled in fields:

```
    def clean(self):
        fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        filled = sum(field in cleaned_data for field in fields)
        if filled < 2:
            raise ValidationError('You need to fill in at least two fields.')
        return cleaned_data
```

Or you can change the check to:

```
sum(field in cleaned_data and cleaned_data['field'] not in (None, '') for field in fields)
```

Comment: `bool(cleaned_data.get(field))` might raise false negatives, ie for numeric fields where zero is a valid value...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: yes, maybe `field` in `cleaned_data` is better. Although for empty strings, that can still produce problems.

Comment: @willem-von-onsem I just checked and it seems that unsubmitted optional fields do indeed appear in `cleaned_data` with default values, so your second check is the right one (assuming no other possible default values). The OP will have to check the exact default values for their optional fields.